# Item Adding and Item Updating triggers on Item Add to list

Tags: 2007, list, event-handlers

my list triggers  item added and then item updated when I add a list item, but then when i add list item it takes me to update item form, where it asks me to update item details, so if i click next, it triggers updatedItem method again

i checked list item add only has item add event related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your code is updating the item in the itemadded method which is firing your item updated event. You need to disable events in your code before making changes to the item and enable after completing your changes.

[this link](http://www.mattjimison.com/blog/2011/05/11/disable-event-receivers-during-an-update/) shows the best way to do this.

Best of luck